# open child window in telerik radwindow

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I want to open a child RadWindow with in a telerik:RadWindow with client side script, i have used "radopen", it showing a window but not exactly with same property and url as I configured.
One more thing my Parent RadWindow is exists in a UserControl

this is my code:

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManagerCustomValue" Style="overflow: hidden"
    ShowContentDuringLoad="false" VisibleStatusbar="false" ReloadOnShow="True" IconUrl=""
    DestroyOnClose="true" Modal="true" Height="390" Width="600" runat="server" OnClientClose="closeRadWindow"
    EnableShadow="true" Title="Add/Edit Agreement Type">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="AddCompanyDialog" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" runat="server"
            Title="Add Company" InitialBehaviors="Maximize" Behaviors="Close" NavigateUrl="somePage.aspx" />
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>



            function LoadCompanyPopup(sender, args) {

                radopen(null, "AddCompanyDialog");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually using JavaScript is the way to work with Telerik's RadWindow. It renders only on the client, so using it on the server is usually done by [injecting scripts](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radwindow-troubleshooting-javascript-from-server-side.html). Take a look at [this thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/opening-radwindow-from-the-server.aspx) on opening it from the server

At the original poster - take a look at these articles - [opening a RadWindow from within a RadWindow](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening-from-within-dialog.html) on opening the second RadWindow properly (so it is not confined in the first) and at [using multiple managers](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radwindow-troubleshooting-wrong-window-opened.html) on the wrong URL you get - most likely you have more than one RadWindowManager on the page in which context you call radopen().

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple Javascript code to open the window:

```
function LoadCompanyPopup()
{ var myWindow=window.radopen(null, "AddCompanyDialog"); }
```

Also, on your telerik:RadWindow tag, change your NavigateUrl attribute value from "somePage.aspx" to "./somePage.aspx" (to make sure the path to your aspx page is located).

Answer (score -1):

My memory is a bit fuzzy since it's been a few months since I had messed with Telerik controls... but something tells me it was hard/not possible to open up a window within a window using javascript.

The code I have for this scenario opens up the window with the .NET code-behind using

```
radWindow.VisibleOnPageLoad = True
```

on a button's `onClick` event

EDIT:

I was mistaken! As rdmptn pointed out below. My sample javascript code for opening up a window inside a window:

```
    function closeWin() {
        GetRadWindow().close();
    }

    function GetRadWindow() {
        var oWindow = null; if (window.radWindow)
            oWindow = window.radWindow; else if (window.frameElement.radWindow)
            oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; return oWindow;
       }

    function ConfirmResult(sender, args) {
        var ajaxManager = $find("radAjaxManager");
        ajaxManager.ajaxRequest(args._argument);

        if (args._argument == "confirm")
            closeWin();
    }

    function OpenConfirmDialog() {
        var window = GetRadWindow().get_windowManager().getWindowByName("DeleteConfirmPopup");
        window.show();
        window.add_close(ConfirmResult);
        setTimeout(function () { window.set_modal(true); }, 0);
    }
```

Comment: This is simply not correct, also using the code-behind would allow you to only access a RadWindow declared in the page that is loaded in the first RadWindow. When you need to open it outside of this page you need to use JavaScript to access the parent page through the frame tree.

Comment: Aha... indeed I was mistaken. I looked at my project way too quickly. It does indeed use javascript and it's handlers to deal with opening windows within windows. 

I was also messing with other libraries while evaluating Telerik, so quite possibly mistook some complaints I had with other products.